# Check whether a command from package is used and modify the style

Tags: packages, conditionals, package-writing

I am trying to create a pagestyle, where \guideNameA is mandatory and if \guideNameB is used then I want modify the page style accordingly. Also I need to modify the document content by checking whether I used \stuNameB is used in preamble. The following is page style

```
\ProvidesPackage{Title}[2020/01/11 v.01 an example package]
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\guideNameA}[1]{\gdef\@guideNameA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@guideNameA}{\texttt{\string\guideNameA} currently not set. Please fix this.}
\newcommand*{\guideNameB}[1]{\gdef\@guideNameA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@guideNameB}{}

\newcommand*{\stuNameA}[1]{\gdef\@stuNameA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@stuNameA}{\texttt{\string\stuNameA} currently not set. Please fix this.}
\newcommand*{\stuUSNA}[1]{\gdef\@stuUSNA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@stuUSNA}{\texttt{\string\stuUSNA} currently not set. Please fix this.}
\newcommand*{\stuNameB}[1]{\gdef\@stuNameB{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@stuNameB}{}
\newcommand*{\stuUSNB}[1]{\gdef\@stuUSNB{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@stuUSNB}{}
\newcommand*{\stuNameC}[1]{\gdef\@stuNameC{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@stuNameC}{}
\newcommand*{\stuUSNC}[1]{\gdef\@stuUSNC{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@stuUSNC}{}

\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[line width = 4pt] ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.75in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-0.75in,0.75in)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{center}

\vspace{1cm}
{\Large\bfseries\@title\unskip\strut\par}
\vspace{0.25cm}
{\Large\bfseries\ PROJECT REPORT\unskip\strut\par}
\vspace{0.25cm}
{\Large\bfseries Submitted by,\unskip\strut\par}
\end{center}
{\noindent\large\bfseries\@stuNameA\unskip\strut}\hfill{\large\bfseries\@stuUSNA\unskip\strut\par}
\vspace{0.25cm}
{\noindent\large\bfseries\@stuNameB\unskip\strut}\hfill{\large\bfseries\@stuUSNB\unskip\strut\par}
\vspace{0.25cm}
{\noindent\large\bfseries\@stuNameC\unskip\strut}\hfill{\large\bfseries\@stuUSNC\unskip\strut\par}
\begin{center}
{\Large\bfseries Under the guidance of \unskip\strut\par}
\end{center}

%%%%%%Check if \guideNameB is used%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%If true %%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\noindent\large\bfseries\@guideNameA\unskip\strut}\hfill{\large\bfseries\@guideNameB\unskip\strut\par}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%Else %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
{\large\bfseries\@guideNameA\unskip\strut\par}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
}
\endinput
```

and the document is

```
\documentclass{book}
%Packages
\usepackage{Title}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Commands used from "Title" %%%%%%%%%% 
\stuNameA{P Narashimaraja}
\stuUSNA{1RV07EC007}
\stuNameB{Nithin M}
\stuUSNB{1RV14EC001}

\guideNameA{Narashimaraja}
\guideNameB{Ramavenkateshwaran}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%If \stuNameB{} command is used, then %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Certified that the major project work titled \textbf{\textit{TITLE}} is carried out by \textbf{STUDENT NAME A} **and \textbf{STUDENT NAME B}**  who **are** bonafide students of College of Engineering
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Else %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Certified that the major project work titled \textbf{\textit{TITLE}} is carried out by \textbf{STUDENT NAME A} who **is** bonafide students of College of Engineering

\end{document}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TeX's `\newif` macro to define booleans. After `\newif\iffoo`, the boolean can be set using `\footrue` or `\foofalse`, and tested using `\iffoo ... \else ... \fi`. Beware that setting booleans respects the grouping rules of TeX: unless preceded by `\global`, such a setting is local to the innermost group. Applying this to your code, I did the following (this includes additions that you didn't mention in your question but seem to desire, as I understood from the comments):

```latex
% Title.sty
...
\newif\ifGuideNameBUsed         % initial state: false
\newif\ifStuNameBUsed           % ditto
...
\newcommand*{\guideNameB}[1]{\gdef\@guideNameB{#1}\global\GuideNameBUsedtrue}
...
\newcommand*{\stuNameB}[1]{\gdef\@stuNameB{#1}\global\StuNameBUsedtrue}
...
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
    ...
    \ifGuideNameBUsed
      ...
    \else
      ...
    \fi
    \vfill
    \CollegeCertification
  \end{titlepage}%
}

\newcommand*{\CollegeCertification}{%
  ...
  \ifStuNameBUsed
    ...
  \else
    ...
  \fi
}
```

Student document:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{Title}
...

\title{The Foo Project}

\stuNameA{P.~Duckafoo}
...
\guideNameA{Prof.~Prof.~Canard}
...

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Student text goes here.

\end{document}
```

I fixed this line from your `Title.sty`:

```latex
\newcommand*{\guideNameB}[1]{\gdef\@guideNameA{#1}}
```

which defines or overwrites `\@guideNameA` instead of `\@guideNameB`. I also fixed the “students” (extra `s` in the single student case) at the end of your sample document. Additionally, `tikz`, its `calc` library and the `graphicx` package can be required from the `Title` package code; there is no need to pollute the preamble of student documents with this, as the `\usepackage{Title}` line will automatically do what is needed (a better name for the package, more specific to the College structure where this package is used, would be a good idea IMHO...). Here is the complete code:

`Title.sty`:

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{Title}[2020/01/24 v0.1 An example package]
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newif\ifGuideNameBUsed         % initial state: false
\newif\ifStuNameBUsed           % ditto

\newcommand*{\guideNameA}[1]{\gdef\@guideNameA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@guideNameA}{\texttt{\string\guideNameA} currently not set. Please fix this.}
\newcommand*{\guideNameB}[1]{\gdef\@guideNameB{#1}\global\GuideNameBUsedtrue}
\newcommand*{\@guideNameB}{}

\newcommand*{\stuNameA}[1]{\gdef\@stuNameA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@stuNameA}{\texttt{\string\stuNameA} currently not set. Please fix this.}
\newcommand*{\stuUSNA}[1]{\gdef\@stuUSNA{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@stuUSNA}{\texttt{\string\stuUSNA} currently not set. Please fix this.}
\newcommand*{\stuNameB}[1]{\gdef\@stuNameB{#1}\global\StuNameBUsedtrue}
\newcommand*{\@stuNameB}{}
\newcommand*{\stuUSNB}[1]{\gdef\@stuUSNB{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@stuUSNB}{}
\newcommand*{\stuNameC}[1]{\gdef\@stuNameC{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@stuNameC}{}
\newcommand*{\stuUSNC}[1]{\gdef\@stuUSNC{#1}}
\newcommand*{\@stuUSNC}{}

\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[line width = 4pt]
      ($(current page.north west) + (0.75in,-0.75in)$) rectangle
      ($(current page.south east) + (-0.75in,0.75in)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{center}

  \vspace{1cm}
  {\Large\bfseries\@title\unskip\strut\par}
  \vspace{0.25cm}
  {\Large\bfseries\ PROJECT REPORT\unskip\strut\par}
  \vspace{0.25cm}
  {\Large\bfseries Submitted by,\unskip\strut\par}
  \end{center}
  {\noindent\large\bfseries\@stuNameA\unskip\strut}\hfill{\large\bfseries\@stuUSNA\unskip\strut\par}
  \vspace{0.25cm}
  {\noindent\large\bfseries\@stuNameB\unskip\strut}\hfill{\large\bfseries\@stuUSNB\unskip\strut\par}
  \vspace{0.25cm}
  {\noindent\large\bfseries\@stuNameC\unskip\strut}\hfill{\large\bfseries\@stuUSNC\unskip\strut\par}
  \begin{center}
  {\Large\bfseries Under the guidance of \unskip\strut\par}
  \end{center}

  \ifGuideNameBUsed
    {\noindent\large\bfseries\@guideNameA\unskip\strut}%
    \hfill
    {\large\bfseries\@guideNameB\unskip\strut\par}%
  \else
    \begin{center}
    {\large\bfseries\@guideNameA\unskip\strut\par}%
    \end{center}%
  \fi
  \vfill
  \CollegeCertification
  \end{titlepage}%
}

\newcommand*{\CollegeCertification}{%
  \noindent
  \ifStuNameBUsed
    Certified that the major project work titled \textbf{\textit{\@title}} is
    carried out by \textbf{\@stuNameA} and \textbf{\@stuNameB} who are
    \emph{bonafide} students of College of Engineering.
  \else
    Certified that the major project work titled \textbf{\textit{\@title}} is
    carried out by \textbf{\@stuNameA} who is a \emph{bonafide} student of
    College of Engineering.
  \fi
}

\endinput
```

Sample student document:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{Title}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\title{The Foo Project}

\stuNameA{P.~Duckafoo}
\stuUSNA{1RV07EC007}
\stuNameB{Q.~Quack}
\stuUSNB{1RV14EC001}

\guideNameA{Prof.~Prof.~Canard}
\guideNameB{Prof.~Dr.~Poulet~Jr.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I have to say I'm not a big fan of the very thick frame and the `\large\bfseries` type in the title page... Anyway, here are screenshots for the four possible cases:

- One supervisor, one student:

[image]

- One supervisor, two students:

[image]

- Two supervisors, one student:

[image]

- Two supervisors, two students:

[image]

## Answer to your last request

Answer to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525499/check-whether-a-command-from-package-is-used-and-modify-the-style/525513?noredirect=1#comment1329410_525513). At the end of `Title.sty`, right before `\endinput`, add:

```latex
\newcommand*{\printStuNameA}{\leavevmode\@stuNameA}
\newcommand*{\printStuNameB}{\leavevmode\@stuNameB}
```

In the student document, you can then use the `\CollegeCertification` macro or something like this:

```latex
\ifStuNameBUsed
  Two students: \printStuNameA\ and \printStuNameB.
\else
  Only one student: \printStuNameA.
\fi
```

If you don't want the last thing I included in the title page, simply remove the line containing `\CollegeCertification` before `\end{titlepage}` in `Title.sty`.

Comment: I need the STUDENT NAME to be substituted from \stuNameA{} and \stuNameB{} commands that I have defined before. Can I use, \@stuNameA, but this can only be used only inside package I belive. So is there is any alternative way to get it?

Comment: Not necessarily, as `\makeatletter` can be used outside the package. But why don't you write a command inside the package that produces the text from the end of the document, that contains the `\ifStuNameBUsed` test plus text with  `\@stuNameA` and `\@stuNameB`?

Comment: @Raja Please check the latest version of the answer. I tried to guess what you want and applied the suggestion I made in the previous comment.

Comment: I need \stuNameA to be used as a content in another page, not on the title page itself. Some how need to use \stuNameA and B anywhere inside the document, which where defined in the preamble.

Comment: @Raja Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you @frougon